# How to drag images from Chrome to PyQt?

Tags: image, qt, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, pyqt

I want to drag a picture from the browser but can not get the URL!

```
if ev.mimeData().hasUrls():
    ev.mimeData().urls()
```

This code works well with images from Firefox(but I sometimes get the link of the image not the source URL of the image - I already have an idea how to fix it).

However, the same code returns an empty list when I drag a image from Chrome.

So, what's the problem?

---

I have tried draging image to default `QlineEdit` widget, and the src url was dropped automaticly both FireFox and Chrome !

————

**Experimental result :**

```
PyQt4 - Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Firefox 32.0                          : Only work with URL, I can't found image type.
Google chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit) : URL is empty and no images founded.

PyQt5 Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2 (Ubuntu14.04)
the same
```

Comment: it may move the image itself which has a `image/*` mimetype Qt has a class to pull those in

Comment: @ratchetfreak I have tried that, but the same. I have add some info which may be helpful to my question.

Answer (score 0):

All data drag & drop in `QWidget` (in PyQt) it must be common MIME types ([`QtCore.QMimeData`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmimedata.html)). It's possibility data are not URL (`text/uri-list`) as in your problem, It maybe MIME see image (`image/ *`) type only, not see URL (But sometime it see both URL and image). But, your can get image data from `QtCore.QMimeData` directly;

Your can try it, use method [`bool QMimeData.hasImage (self)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmimedata.html#hasImage) to check type is image. And put image to `QImage` by call [`QVariant QMimeData.imageData (self)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmimedata.html#imageData), see example how to implement;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomQWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomQWidget, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.mimeQLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        allQHBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.mimeQLabel)
        self.setLayout(allQHBoxLayout)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent (self, eventQDragEnterEvent):
        eventQDragEnterEvent.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent (self, eventQDropEvent):
        self.mimeQLabel.clear()
        if eventQDropEvent.mimeData().hasImage():
            mimeQImage = QtGui.QImage(eventQDropEvent.mimeData().imageData())
            self.mimeQLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(mimeQImage))
        elif eventQDropEvent.mimeData().hasUrls():
            self.mimeQLabel.setText('\n'.join([str(url) for url in eventQDropEvent.mimeData().urls()]))
        QtGui.QWidget.dropEvent(self, eventQDropEvent)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQCustomQWidget = QCustomQWidget()
myQCustomQWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Experimental result :**

```
PyQt4 - Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Firefox 31.0                          : Image & URL work fine.
Google chrome Version 37.0.2062.103 m : Only work with URL, I can't found image type.
```

Comment: Your code works well, but it fails when I ported it to `python3.4.0` and `PyQt5`. Any suggestion?

Comment: And I have added some info to my question.

Comment: Your say it work well in your environment with python27 & pyqt4, but fails in python34 pyqt5 ? Very odd. It's possibility google chrome is use different MIME of image ?  Could your please give me about your environment ? Thanks.

Comment: my env is `Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit)` `Ubuntu 14.04` `python3.4.0` `PyQt5`

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and firefox use different additional mime formats when you drag something from them.
You can examine all the mime formats with

```
print(ev.mimeData().formats)
```

You can drag an image from chrome with this snippet.

```
if ev.mimeData().hasFormat("application/octet-stream"):
    image = QImage()
    image.loadFromData(ev.mimeData().data("application/octet-stream"))
```